# what is efficient way to decrease cpu usage for delivering homepage in wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, caching, cpu-usage

i have an ecommerce website and i want to speed up my home page. i had done this to some extent by using wp super cache, but server response time to start loading my home page is not good enough, and i also wnat to minimize cpu usage. My home page changed only from admin and not according to user query or login info. what if i create static homepage outside wordpress directory that rewrite its html when i changed it from admin. so that there is no load on my cpu hosting when user requested as they directly got the static html page. does it better than caching pages which requires the loading of wordpress framework before loading my homepage

Answer (score 0):

You should use a CDN (content delivery network), to speed up your wordpress site.
You can load all your static files (css,js,images) from the CDN which will speed up your site and also save a hit to your server thus saving your processor work.
CloudFlare is a free CDN provider which can help in your case.

You should go thorough how to speed up wordpress site using CDN here:
https://blog.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-tips-speeding-up-your-wordpress-bl/

Answer (score 0):

Your idea to create static homepage outside wordpress directory that rewrite its html when i changed it from admin is too complicated.
First of all, check Cache Timeout setting in WP Cache plugin - it should be 0.
Second, create common cash from within plugin.
Third, try to experiment with plugin settings for better results.
You can also use WP debug function to show information.

Still it seems that the main load for your page are 1) images 2) js.
In this case you should try to use CDN, as it was recommended in @Shakti Phartiyal 's answer.